# How can i modify the position CSS style property of my modal pop-up

Tags: css, simplemodal

I have this jquery bpopup momadal that i want to position relative to the co-ordinates of the mouse click. i am able to capture the cordinate and pass them to the style sheet or even when i code them explicitly the modal doesnt seem to support the possitioning property.

Please check out the JS fidle of the modal that i am using on this        link:  http://jsfiddle.net/24a9b/

```
#element_to_pop_up { 
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:15px;
    color:#000;
    display:none; 
    padding:20px;
    min-width:400px;
    min-height: 180px;
}
.bClose{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:5px;
}
```

I want to use the "top" and "left" style properties. but it seems this modal has the center as a default writen in its library wich you can also check out on that link. Please any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library which you have used to create this popup modal is setting the modal in **center** by calculating the `top` and `left` styles dynamically and then it applies them to the element in the form of inline css styles.

Therefore, if you want to **override** the `top` and `left` to provide your own values, you can do this by giving your styles as `!important`.

```
#element_to_pop_up { 
    left: 10px !important;
    top:10px  !important;
}
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24A9b/13946/

Comment: Work perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
left: 10px !important;
```

Because the modal's position is already calculated and assigned inline by a script of the library you are using.

`!important` will give the targeted element left/top precedence over any css styling that targets the same element.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `position` property to the `bPopup` method, which will hold the `x` and `y` position as an array like this.

```
$('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
    position: [10,100]
});
```

To pass the `x` and `y` mouse co-ordinates to the popup this would be an option.

```
$('#my-button').bind('click', function(e) {

    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var x = (e.pageX - offset.left);
    var y = (e.pageY - offset.top);

    // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
    e.preventDefault();

    // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
    $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        position: [x,y]
    });

});
```

Here is a working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qsz1cyyk/)